# Warp divergence

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, multithreading

Suppose a warp contains 32 threads whereby there are 32  SIMD lanes in the GPU. Each thread computes one iteration of the loop

```
for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
    if (A[j] > 20) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now suppose that for each 0 <= j < 32,  A[j] > 20 and A[j+1] <= 20 so there is branch divergence.  Why is this bad for SIMD utilisation (warp divergence), because since every thread has  its own SIMD lane if one thread executes a different branch this shouldn't affect the others since they do it in parallel, not? I'm very  new to this topic so I apologise in advance if this question  is poorly formulated.

*We define the SIMD utilization of a program that runs on a GPU as the fraction of SIMD lanes that are kept busy with active threads during the run of the program.*

Comment: You write "why is this bad for SIMD utilization", but GPU warps are *not generally* SIMD-related; this is very much the special case of SIMT.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  it's an  exercise of my Computer architecture course, so I don't know what to say...

Comment: It's really not an electrical engineering problem, let's migrate it to stackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

Since different SIMD lanes cannot do different operations at the same time, the GPU compiler transforms the code so that both the `if` and `else` case are computed by all the lane (by different instructions). The computation is masked so that results appear not to be computed by all the lane from the user point-of-view. However, this trick strongly impact the performance of the program. This is why this is not good.

To be more clear about what is going on under the hood, here is an example of possible generated assembly code:

```
reg_0 <- load 32 int32_t from *A
mask_0 <- reg_0 > 20                                  (mask_0 is a SIMD register of 32 booleans)
mask_1 <- not mask_0
reg_1 <- operation based on reg_0 masked by mask_0    (if)
reg_2 <- operation based on reg_0 masked by mask_1    (else)
reg_3 <- reg_1 or reg_2                               (merge/blend of the two results)
```